# How to perform deep search when using PynamoDB for DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am using PynamoDB for AWS DynamoDB in python, and having a table like this:

```
{company_name:'abc', address:{suburb:'Melbourne', state:'VIC'}}
```

And I need to do a search to get all companies with state equals to 'VIC', is it possible using PynamoDB, or what is the best way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: What is the data type of address? Is it defined as map?

Comment: @notionquest It is defined as JSONAttribute in PynamoDB model

Comment: I am asking the DynamoDB data type for address? Have you inserted an item into DynamoDB? If yes, you can check the item to get the DynamoDB data type. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html

Comment: @notionquest I am using PynamoDB, it doesn't have a MAP type attribute, i am using the JOSN which is a string after saved into the table.

Comment: @Stephen.Y just in case you still need this - `MapAttribute` was introduced into PynamoDB in v2.0.0, i.e., one month later after you had asked this question. `MapAttribute` does exactly what you're looking for.